# Python 3 and Gspread ImportError

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, gspread

When I run Gspread with Python3, I get this error:

> ImportError: No module named 'gspread'

When I run with just Python, I get no errors. I installed gspread with `pip install gspread --user`. I really need to use Python 3, and I expect I should be able to, but I just did something wrong.

Comment: can you see gspread in pip freeze?

Comment: try `pip3 install gspread --user`

Comment: @KalyanReddy I do, it says gspread==0.6.2

Comment: @PRMoureu that worked - thank you!!

Comment: you might have two pips, do what @PRMoureu suggested, it might work

Comment: I would suggest you install it with using pip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install your `pip update` in an environment? Doing

```
 pip3 install gspread --user
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct interpreter.

You may have one or more python interpreters installed so it may be installing to a different one.

Comment: Any suggestions for the person to check your assumption?

Comment: Well if they are in visual studio code, or any relevant IDE. They should be able to press CRTL shift P. Then type in python interpreter. If there are multiple Python versions to choose from, they may need to change their interpreter from the list given.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install pip for python3 using apt install python3-pip

Then you can install using pip3 install gspread --user

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this issue, running

```
python -m pip install gspread
```

instead of

```
pip install gspread
```

did the trick for me.